# Firebase-Admin with AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

I am currently writing a Python server to deploy on AWS Lambda. I want to use the firebase-admin package to send notifications with FCM and read data from cloud firestore. however when I try deploying my function to AWS Lambda with the .zip file archives, I get this error on execution:

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.`

I installed the module with this: `pip install --target . firebase-admin` into a folder, added my code files (to the root as instructed), zipped it recursively and uploaded it with the aws-cli, I can clearly see that there is a google-cloud-firestore folder inside the .zip so i'm not sure whats going on. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the firebase-admin package uses some libraries that are compiled differently on different OSes, so you need to create a docker image and install everything there, zip it up and upload it as a layer. Here is an example docker file:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20210126.0

RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" && \
yum -y install openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel && \
yum -y install wget && \
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.7/Python-3.8.7.tgz && \
yum install -y tar && \
yum install -y gzip && \
tar xvf Python-3.8.7.tgz && \
cd Python-3.8*/ && \
./configure --enable-optimizations && \
make altinstall && \
yum install -y zip && \
yum clean all


RUN python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
python3.8 -m pip install virtualenv

RUN python3.8 -m venv myvenv
RUN source myvenv/bin/activate
RUN pip install firebase-admin -t ./python
RUN deactivate
RUN zip -r python.zip ./python/
```

And then copy the zip file:

```
docker cp container_name:python.zip ./Desktop/
```

Comment: For me ` RUN deactivate`  failed with error `deactivate: command not found`. I had to do without virtual environment

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [LambdaLayer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

There are a bunch of resources on that online, but essentially you want to make a Zip file in this format*:

> myLayer.zip/
> -- python/
> ---- lib/
> ------ python**X.Y**/
> -------- site-packages/
> ---------- *firebase-admin*
> ---------- ...

<sup>*where **X.Y** is the python version you're targetting</sup>

Then, either in the AWS console or in your CI/CD, you can add that LambdaLayer in your Function's configuration, which lets you import all the libraries in it.

Comment: This actually worked for you??I followed this and its definitely not working

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it you have bundled your code correctly and deployed successfully. The error occurs because Firestore relies on a C-based implementation of GRPC. By default this does not work on AWS Lambda. I'm currently creating a work-around and will update this post with my results.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful for next people if someone could explain how to run a docker file.

I'm not an expert, so what I've done was to create a docker instance based on the image mentioned, then I executed each command individually within the CLI, and lastly, since I wasn't able to zip and copy the files from my container to the desktop, I had to find the folder through my windows explorer within the Linux virtual enviroment so that I could ZIP and bring.

It actually worked, but again, will be very helpful if someone can complement the best answer by letting everyone know how to build and execute a docker file.

Best!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33039958)